# Show part of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I show a part of the image using jQuery or another JavaScript technique?

Example:

```
image:
[                ]
[     --------   ]
[     -      -   ]
[     - part -   ]
[     -      -   ]
[     --------   ]
[                ]
```

Comment: you'll have to elaborate the question.

Comment: You can do that using CSS.

Comment: Agree to ThiefMaster, create a DIV with specified width and height and set image as background image with given background-position in CSS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Manipulate the CSS property `background`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wGpk9/):

```
#imgDiv {
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-position: 10px 50px; /* Visible coordinates in image */
    height: 200px; /* Visible height */
    width: 200px; /* Visible width */
}
```

Here's how to `.animate` the visible part: http://jsfiddle.net/wGpk9/2/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a div with fixed size and place the image absolutely positioned inside. You can then use javascript to change the top / left / right / bottom position of the image to move it.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; position: relative"> 
  <img src="path" alt="something" id="image"  
      style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" />
</div>

...
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveImage() {
   document.getElementById('image').style.top = '-100px';
}
</script>
```

EDIT: that's if you want to move the image over time... Otherwise simply use CSS

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's example works if you add style overflow:hidden to the div like so..

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;"> 
  <img src="path" alt="something" id="image"  
      style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" />
</div>

...
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveImage() {
   document.getElementById('image').style.top = '-100px';
}
</script>
```