# Bootstrap 4 Carousel "Half of previous"

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to create this Carousel in Bootstrap 4.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0zpS.jpg

Website: https://www.omaze.com/ (live demo)

I started with default Owl Carousel Bootstrap 4. 
The whole point is to create this "half of previous" slider.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: welcome to SO! for you to help with the issue, you HAVE to either show the code or have to show what you have achieved.

Comment: you need to show what you have done so far so we can help.

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply. I simply add "Owl Carousel" default from Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Can anyone help, I explained in detail what help I needed.

Answer (score -1):

First import Bootstrap as a link in the head tag of the HTML file.

```
<head>
 [...]
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Then make this where the carousel shoul be.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="[PATH_TO_IMG]" class="d-block w-100" alt="[ALTERNATIVE_TEXT]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="[PATH_TO_IMG]" class="d-block w-100" alt="[ALTERNATIVE_TEXT]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="[PATH_TO_IMG]" class="d-block w-100" alt="[ALTERNATIVE_TEXT]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to make **4 Images** in your slideshow than you have to make this **4 times**: named as *[1]* by me.

```
 <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="[PATH_TO_IMG]" class="d-block w-100" alt="[ALTERNATIVE_TEXT]">
    </div>
```

If you want buttons, put this after the last block of *[1]*:

```
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Comment: Hello Greil, thank you so much for a fast response. I tried code and It's default carousel from bootstrap. Can you help me to get something similar from the image.

Comment: if I know want you want, yes. If the corners should be rounded than you have to add the rounded at the class from the image

Comment: Bootstrap 4 isn't able to make half of the previous and the next image to the current, as I know.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 will just use to get carousel code (js and CSS which I can use) after that I can customize with my custom CSS.. but that's the point. Need that "half of previous".

Comment: maybe there is a better way, but I am not good at *.js. My Idee: If you want 3 images, put them to 1. For example all 3 images are 300*400px. put dem to a 300*1200 image. Than make a div and put the img in. But make only the Range of 200 to 800px avariable to view. Than if you click next: 800 to 600px and so on... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808534/show-part-of-an-image